# How can I parse this JSON properly?

Tags: php

I am having a hard time getting the values when trying to parse some JSON. Here is an example of what I am working with.

```
{
"key": "",
"data":"[{
    \"id\":1,
    \"urls\":[{
        \"url1\":\"http://example1.com\",
        \"url2\":\"http://example2.com\"
    }],
    \"cat_id\":1,
    \"info\":{
        \"color\":\"red\"
    },
    \"description\":\"Example Description\",
    \"extra_info\":{
        \"stuff\":\"example stuff\",
        \"sizes\":[{
            \"size1\":\"small\",
            \"size2\":\"large\"
    }]},
    \"currently_available\":true,
    \"stock\":15
    },
    {
    \"id\":2,
    \"urls\":[{
        \"url1\":\"http://example3.com\",
        \"url2\":\"http://example4.com\"
        }],
        \"cat_id\":2,
        \"info\":{
            \"color\":\"blue\"
        },
        \"description\":\"Example Description\",
        \"extra_info\":{
            \"stuff\":\"example stuff\",
            \"sizes\":[{
                \"size1\":\"small\",
                \"size2\":\"large\"
        }]},
    \"currently_available\":true,
    \"stock\":15}]"
}
```

I was unable to parse the JSON normally so I came up with this.

```
$json = '
{
     "key": "",
     "data":"[{\"id\":1,\"urls\":[{\"url1\":\"http://example1.com\",\"url2\":\"http://example2.com\"}],\"cat_id\":1,\"info\":{\"color\":\"red\"},\"description\":\"Example Description\",\"extra_info\":{\"stuff\":\"example stuff\",\"sizes\":[{\"size1\":\"small\",\"size2\":\"large\"}]},\"currently_available\":true,\"stock\":15},{\"id\":2,\"urls\":[{\"url1\":\"http://example3.com\",\"url2\":\"http://example4.com\"}],\"cat_id\":2,\"info\":{\"color\":\"blue\"},\"description\":\"Example Description\",\"extra_info\":{\"stuff\":\"example stuff\",\"sizes\":[{\"size1\":\"small\",\"size2\":\"large\"}]},\"currently_available\":true,\"stock\":15}]"
}
';

$result = json_decode($json);
$arr = array();
$values = Extract_Vals($result->data, $arr);
print_r($values);

function Extract_Vals($data, $arr){
    $pattern = '@(?:"id":)([\d]+)@';
    preg_match_all($pattern, $data, $m);  
    $pattern = '@(?:"url1":")([\w\W]*?)(")@';
    preg_match_all($pattern, $data, $m2); 
    $pattern = '@(?:"url2":")([\w\W]*?)(")@';
    preg_match_all($pattern, $data, $m3); 
    $pattern = '@(?:"cat_id":)([\d]+)@';
    preg_match_all($pattern, $data, $m4); 
    $pattern = '@(?:"color":")([\w\W]*?)(")@';
    preg_match_all($pattern, $data, $m5); 
    $pattern = '@(?:"description":")([\w\W]*?)(")@';
    preg_match_all($pattern, $data, $m6); 
    $pattern = '@(?:"size1":")([\w\W]*?)(")@';
    preg_match_all($pattern, $data, $m7); 
    $i = 0;
    foreach($m[1] as $e){
        $data_array = Array(
        $e,
        $m2[1][$i],
        $m3[1][$i],
        $m4[1][$i],
        $m5[1][$i],
        $m6[1][$i],
        $m7[1][$i]
    );
    $arr[] = $data_array;
    $i++;
}
return $arr;  
}
```

My code seems to work fine but usually I just do a simple loop so I am wondering if anyone has a better idea to get the values or can show me how to get them properly in a regular loop if possible. Thanks.

Comment: Is that not just JSON within JSON? I.e. you'd need to decode twice, once with the main content, then from the `data` property?

Comment: It seems the value associated with the `data` key is also a JSON. Decode it using `json_decode($result->data)`. I recommend you pass `TRUE` as the second argument to [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to ask it to produce arrays instead of objects. PHP arrays are more versatile than the `stdClass` instances and there are dozens of [array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) to handle them. Check this out: https://3v4l.org/BqK4H

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the value associated with the `data` key is also a JSON. Decode it using `json_decode($result->data)`.

I recommend you pass `TRUE` as the second argument to [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to ask it to produce arrays instead of objects. PHP arrays are more versatile than the `stdClass` instances and there are dozens of [array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) to handle them.

All the code you need is:

```
$json = '
{
     "key": "",
     "data":"[{\"id\":1,\"urls\":[{\"url1\":\"http://example1.com\",\"url2\":\"http://example2.com\"}],\"cat_id\":1,\"info\":{\"color\":\"red\"},\"description\":\"Example Description\",\"extra_info\":{\"stuff\":\"example stuff\",\"sizes\":[{\"size1\":\"small\",\"size2\":\"large\"}]},\"currently_available\":true,\"stock\":15},{\"id\":2,\"urls\":[{\"url1\":\"http://example3.com\",\"url2\":\"http://example4.com\"}],\"cat_id\":2,\"info\":{\"color\":\"blue\"},\"description\":\"Example Description\",\"extra_info\":{\"stuff\":\"example stuff\",\"sizes\":[{\"size1\":\"small\",\"size2\":\"large\"}]},\"currently_available\":true,\"stock\":15}]"
}
';

$result = json_decode($json, TRUE);
$data = json_decode($result['data'], TRUE);
```

A quick look at `$data` reveals that it was correctly encoded and can be decoded (it is `NULL` if it cannot be decoded):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [urls] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [url1] => http://example1.com
                            [url2] => http://example2.com
                        )
                )
            [cat_id] => 1
            [info] => Array
                (
                    [color] => red
                )
            [description] => Example Description
            [extra_info] => Array
                (
                    [stuff] => example stuff
                    [sizes] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [size1] => small
                                    [size2] => large
                                )
                        )
                )
            [currently_available] => 1
            [stock] => 15
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [urls] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [url1] => http://example3.com
                            [url2] => http://example4.com
                        )
                )
            [cat_id] => 2
            [info] => Array
                (
                    [color] => blue
                )
            [description] => Example Description
            [extra_info] => Array
                (
                    [stuff] => example stuff
                    [sizes] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [size1] => small
                                    [size2] => large
                                )
                        )
                )
            [currently_available] => 1
            [stock] => 15
        )
)
```

Comment: Nice, that works. Thanks a lot. I'll accept your answer in a few minutes when it lets me.